# while getting an error user should not allow into another row/column in cell value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

In my windows form I have validation tab control in my tab control  implemented the data table with rows and columns if user give the duplicate name in second row/column same name as first row an error will come if user click on error button again user  should be in same row and column user should not allow into another row/column so tell me how I can stop user do not allow into another cell if user get an error
please get the code in the cell leave event

Answer (score 0):

You should add conditions to your data grid view's CellValidating event and call cancel if needed. Please refer to [DataGridView.CellValidating Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "";
        // Don't try to validate the 'new row' until finished 
        // editing since there
        // is not any point in validating its initial value.
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow) { return; }

        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        bool isValid = true;
        // Convert grid view rows to an IEnumerable collection
        IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow> _dataRows = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>();
        // Loop through grid view rows
        for (int i = 0; i < _dataRows.Count(); i++)
        {
            if(row.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value == _dataRows.ElementAt(i).Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value)
            {
                isValid = false;
                break; // To break from current loop
            }
        }

        if (!isValid)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "No duplicate values allowed.";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you so specific about cell leave event. The best practice is to have dataGridView1_CellValidating event or [dataGridView1_CellValueChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellleave(v=vs.110).aspx).
If you need to get the value for comparing use.

```
    var c = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value; // got value and proceed for comparing.
```

in dataGridView1_CellValueChanged event

Comment: can you give me further code if user click on error button and to stop user do not enter into another cell until user fill the current cell for non-duplicate values